# Join syntax on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

For MYSQL syntax I understand the Joins are FROM table JOIN table ON table.column = table.column I have come across other forms of joins that seam to not only not follow that syntax but the two columns do not relate rather they compliment each-other example below

```
 from coordinates as cod join
      geofences as geo
      on st_contains(geo.simplified_shape, cod.request_point)
```

For context this is saying st_contains where A contains B so essentially is this satisfying the join if indeed the request point is in the geo fence shape? I know this is a valid syntax this question is more on if someone can illuminate not only the joins within a parentheses and when that can be applicable rather than the = sign is it only in these specific instances and if my line of thinking is correct that the tables can join not because the values are equivalent but because it satisfies the st_contains condition so for example if you used something else other then st_contains how would that look?

Comment: `=` is the most common operator, but you can use whatever expression returning true/false/null.

Comment: The `ON` expression can be any condition, it doesn't have to be `=`

Comment: You are just asking how join works. That is a faq & available in any textbook or manual. Please don't ask us to write another one. Ask about where you are stuck in one.  Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: @philipxy I understand Joins but have not come across that particular syntax it is clearly a less common caveat to a join and was not clear to as exactly why although I could surmise I wanted to consult more experienced people to be sure if the question is superfluous  why waste time to comment clearly other people were happy to help me thank you Gordon Linoff

Comment: I told you some helpful things for getting answers & better voting & not having to ask questions. Research is expected before posting otherwise askers are wasting the time of answerers. If you looked at a grammar you would "come across that syntax".

Answer (score 2):

This is really equivalent to:

```
on st_contains(geo.simplified_shape, cod.request_point) <> 0
```

What is happening here is that MySQL is converting the result to a "boolean".  If the function returns a number, then any non-zero number is "true" and zero is "false".

If the returned value is a string, then the string is converted to a number, based on the leading digits.  If there are no leading digits, the value is zero.  Then this is treated as a boolean.